# Textbox.Select(0, 0) does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, textbox, multiline, cursor-position

I have developed a windows application for chatting. I am using a multi-line text box for typing chat message. After the typing the message, user has to press Enter or click send button for sending the message to other end. Both actions are calling btnSend_Click(). Here is the code

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtChat.Text.Trim()))
            {
                CreateNewMessage(txtChat.Text.Trim());
                txtChat.Clear();
                txtChat.Select(0, 0);
            }
        }
```

But the txtChat.Select(0, 0) does not bring the cursor to the very beginning of the text box. The cursor always come to the start position of the second line after pressing Enter/ or click send button. Why this code does not working? Please explain me. Please suggest me a way to fix this.

P.S - Is there any other methods to position the Cursor at the Beginning of a multi-line text box?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The thing your code does just before setting the selection is to clear all of the text. If you still have text in the control at a later time, it must have been added _after_ you set the selection; but adding text can modify the selection. If you want to keep the selection at the beginning after you've added/set text in the control, you need to call the `Select()` method _after_ you've done that, not before. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows what you are asking.

Comment: Did you mean focus ??

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I want to bring the cursor to the very beginning of the text box. I think txtChat.Select(0, 0); should do that. But it is not happening in my case. It is my problem. Thank you for considering my question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for you problem. Please replace

```
txtChat.Clear();
txtChat.Select(0, 0);
```

to

```
txtChat.ResetText(); // it will reset the entire textbox once you click button.
txtChat.Focus(); // this will keep the focus back to text box and bring the cursor back to the very beginning of the textbox.
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I want to bring the cursor to the very beginning of the text box. I think txtChat.Select(0, 0); should do that. But it is not happening in my case. It is my problem. Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: @KushanRandima Please implement my suggestion, it will fix the problem. Once user clicks the `Send` button the cusor will reach the beginning of the text box. I have implmented it in my applications and then only suggested you.

Comment: I just tried your solution. I am sorry, it is not working for me. Even though my application is a windows forms application, I use addin express for developing that. This form is an ADX form. Some times it may work as a different way. Some how I was able to come up with a work around. (By adding SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}"); as the last line below my present code)

Comment: Oh some one has down-voted your answer. I feel sorry for that. I appreciate the effort that you have taken to solve my problem. Cheers!

Comment: @KushanRandima I am sorry :(. I thought its a normal windows form application so thought of suggesting the answer. Actaully I dont have sufficient points to comment the suggestions so I had to make it as answer post. You are not using visual studio as your IDE for development? What error you are getting while trying this suggestion?

Comment: @KushanRandima Someone has downvoted this question but I have upvoted .. becuase I understand the restrictions while having less points... please upvote for me too.. :P.. Becuase if you will not upvote I might be have ban on answering the questions. :(